# How to get laravel 5.2 ADLDAP provider instance in mycontroller?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and ADLDAP2 Lib for LDAP authentication, i want to get all users from my Active Directory, for this i want to use this method:

```
$results = $provider->search()->where('cn', '=', 'John Doe')->get();
```

but i don't know hot to get instance of LDAP provider.

Comment: Do you have access to your ad server? Please also edit your tags, either laravel-5 or laravel-5.2

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using something like `adldap2/adldap2-laravel` Have you made sure you've hooked in the service provider and Fascade? Without those Laravel don't Inject the provider into the system.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of Adldap2 here. If you're using the Adldap2-Laravel package, use the included façade:

```
use Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap;

$results = Adldap::getProvider('default')->search()->where('cn', '=', 'John Doe')->get();

// Or:

$results = Adldap::getDefaultProvider()->search()->where('cn', '=', 'John Doe')->get();

// Or call `search()` directly and your default provider will be used:

$results = Adldap::search()->where('cn', '=', 'John Doe')->get();
```

Alternatively, you can also resolve it out of the container by its alias:

```
$ldap = app('adldap');

$ldap->search()->users()->get();
```

Or by its interface:

```
$ldap = app(\Adldap\AdldapInterface::class);
```

Inside of a controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controller;
use Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   /**
    * Displays all LDAP users
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = Adldap::search()->users()->get();

        return view('ldap.users', compact('users'));
    }
}
```